# How to give json values from array to dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have array inside its stored json values.when i try to give this value to dictionary its given error.

```
 arrhole{
        "cust_groups" = "";
        "customer_id" = 1;
        "customer_name " = "";
        "date_added" = "<null>";
        "delivery_method" = "";
        fname = kishore;
        gift = "";
        lname = kumar;
        message = "";
        month = "";
        "order_id" = 1;
        "pay_method" = "";
        "payment_firstname" = "";
        "payment_lastname" = "";
        phone = 9043563659;
        region = "";
        reward = "";
        "scheduled_date" = "28/08/2015";
        "sen_email" = "";
        "sen_name" = "";
        "shipping_city" = "";
        "shipping_company" = "";
        "shipping_country" = IND;
        "shipping_region" = 1503;
        "unit_price" = 22;
        voucher = "";
    }
```

This code i have used:

```
 -(void)responseFunction:(NSMutableDictionary *)response
    {
        NSLog(@"response method%@",response);
        BOOL success;
        success =[[response objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];
        arrHoleOrderDetails =[response objectForKey:@"order"];
        NSLog(@"arrhole%@",arrHoleOrderDetails);
        if(success)
        {
            for (NSDictionary *dic in arrHoleOrderDetails)
            {

                NSLog(@"dic===%@",dic);
            }
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
dic===city
 dic===shipping_address
 dic===shipping_lastname
 dic===pay_method
 dic===customer_id
 dic===country
 dic===region
```

like this its displaying in my log.i displaying here only some values.

1.Is it json response problem?

2.or its my silly mistake?

Full Response:

```
 order =     {
        address = "";
        address1 = "";
        address2 = "";
        affliate = "";
        amount = "";
        city = "";
        comment = "";
        company = "";
        "company_id" = "";
        country = "";
        coupon = "";
        "cust_groups" = "";
        "customer_id" = 2;
        "customer_name " = "";
        "date_added" = "<null>";
        "delivery_method" = "";
        email = "";
        fax = "";
        fname = arun;
        gift = "";
        lname = "";
        message = "";
        month = "";
        "order_id" = 2;
        "pay_method" = "";
        "payment_firstname" = "";
        "payment_lastname" = "";
        phone = "";
        postcode = "";
        product = 4;
        quantity = 5;
        "rec_email" = "";
        "rec_name" = "";
        region = "";
        reward = "";
        "scheduled_date" = "28/08/2015";
        "sen_email" = "";
        "sen_name" = "";
        "shipping_address" = "";
        "shipping_address1" = "";
        "shipping_address2" = "";
        "shipping_city" = "";
        "shipping_company" = "";
        "shipping_country" = "";
        "shipping_firstname" = "";
        "shipping_lastname" = "";
        "shipping_postcode" = "";
        "shipping_region" = "";
        status = "";
        stores = "";
        total = "";
        "unit_price" = 540;
        voucher = "";
    };
    success = 1;
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly want? because you have array of strings

Comment: How do you want to treat this arrHoleOrderDetails array?

Comment: That is my json response i have stored in array,and i need to show that in label,so i am passing the values from array to dictionary ,but i mentioned output above like that i get.

Comment: Actually in json response, you get dictionary named "order".

Comment: yes correct.... @iPhone

Comment: You didn't give us full response - there is no "success" key in your dictionary in question and also no "order" key. Also you didn't show output of NSLog(@"arrhole%@",arrHoleOrderDetails);

Comment: Have you only this response from json or you have more than 1 array in json response?

Comment: only this response i have in this json @iPhone

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski i gave that as per your suggestion please verify that.

Comment: your Json Response Format is wrong bro..

Comment: kindly mention whats wrong in the json response bro i need to explain it @SandyPatel

Comment: i have little change {
        "cust_groups" : "",
        "customer_id" : 1,
        "customer_name " : ""
        
  },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
   -(void)responseFunction:(NSMutableDictionary *)response
        {
            NSLog(@"response method%@",response);
            BOOL success;
            success =[[response objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];
            arrHoleOrderDetails =[response objectForKey:@"order"];
            NSLog(@"arrhole%@",arrHoleOrderDetails);
            if(success)
            {
                yourlable.text = [arrHoleOrderDdetails valueForKey:@"address"];
                yourlabel2.text = [arrHoleOrderDdetails valueForKey:@"address1"];

//In case of integer value try following
yourlbl3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[arrHoleOrderDdetails valueForKey:@"address1"]];

    //go ahead in same manner.

    }
```

Comment: kindly explain whats wrong in my json format ,because i need to inform it bro @iphone

Comment: If you have any integer value then convert it in string.

Comment: Actually you have array of strings not dictionary so no need to use for loop. You can directly assigned these values to your UILabel

Comment: but convert your integer value in string otherwise it will crash your app

Comment: its working for me ...but i like to know whats problem in previous code.

Comment: Actually it was string in your array not dictionary in your array and you were trying to fetch dictionary from your array

Comment: so if i have multiple array values inside json then i have to go for dictionary ,i am correct

Comment: In your order dictionary, currently 1 array is there but if you have multiple array then you have to use for loop but in your case that structure didn't work. At that time json response structure will be different.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
if(success)
{
    //display all keys and values
    for (NSString* key in [arrHoleOrderDetails allKeys])
    {
        NSString* value = [arrHoleOrderDetails objetForKey:key];
        NSLog(@"%@===%@",key, value);
    }

    //access single value
    NSLog(@"%@", arrHoleOrderDetails[@"scheduled_date"]);
}
```

If you iterate on NSDictionary, you need to iterate on keys and get values for given key.
Also remember that NSDictionaries are access randomly - not having any order.